# Django - static/CACHE files not found

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm using Django 1.10 + uWsgi + nginx.
In Prod mode the static files do not show up, this is what my nginx error-log tells me:

```
404   ... static/CACHE/js/e3a6fa7588d1.js" failed (2: No such file or directory),
```

The folder `static/CACHE` remains empty (so the 404's make sense), but why? 
I already set the permissions to `775` for `static/CACHE` .

nginx conf:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites/available/mysite_nginx.conf
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream bdjango {
   server unix:///tmp/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
}
# configuration of the server
server {
   # the port your site will be served on
   listen 80;

   # the domain name it will serve for
   server_name dev.mysite.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
   charset utf-8;

   # max upload size
   client_max_body_size 8M; # adjust to taste

   # Django media
   location /media {
      alias /var/www/mysite/src/media; # your Django project's media files - amend as required
   }
   location /static {
      alias /var/www/mysite/src/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
   }
   # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
   location / {
      uwsgi_pass adjango;
      include /var/www/mysite/src/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
   }
}
```

Django settings contains

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "../../../")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

So, why are my js/css files not in `static/CACHE` ?

**EDIT:**
solved it: uwsgi_pass was pointing at the wrong upstream location (which happened to be a different website):
      `uwsgi_pass adjango;`

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you using CACHE?
2. Have you defiened STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT correctly.
3. Is DEBUG = False?
4. Are you using any 3rd party tool to cache/pipline your static files?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `django-compressor` is failing.

Have you tried having `DEBUG = True` and `COMPRESS_ENABLED = True` in your settings and seeing if it works?

https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_ENABLED

Alternatively, I suggest having `ADMINS` setup in production so it emails you any errors, or setup [sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) in your production setup.

Comment: I already have. The files are copies to the `/static` , however, it is looking for the (minified) files in `static/CACHE` , which is empty.

Comment: Is that `django-compressor`?

Comment: Yes it is.  but it doesn't seem to create the files.

Comment: It could be that django-compressor is failing.  Have you tried having `DEBUG = True` and `COMPRESS_ENABLED = True` and seeing if it works?  Alternatively, I suggest having `ADMINS` setup in production so it emails you any errors, or setup `sentry` in your production.